# Yii won't load a model

Tags: php, model-view-controller, yii

I am unable to load a model in my `NewController`. In other controllers I can perfectly call this line:

```
$vid = Video::model()->findByPk($id);
```

and it will get me the right model.

However in this controller: `NewController.php` it doesn't work.

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    $model=$this->loadModel($id);

    $vid = Video::model()->findByPk($id);

    if(isset($vid)) // Check if it works.
       $this->render('update',array('model'=>$model, 'vid'=>$vid));
}
```

Does anyone have any suggestions why it doesn't work?

`$id` is valid and so is `$model`, I am going insane with this not working when it should.

---

An example that works `UserController.php`:

```
public function actionView()
{
    if(isset($_GET['user']))
        $username = $_GET['user'];          
    else 
        $username = Yii::app()->user->name;

    $user = User::model()->find("username=:username",array(':username'=>$username));
    $saveQ = SavedQuery::model()->findAll("FK_userid=:id", array(':id'=>$user->id));

    $vid = Video::model()->findByPk($user->id);
    $this->render('View', array('user'=>$user, 'vid'=>$vid, 'saveQ'=>$saveQ));
}
```

Comment: are you sure $id is properly set up?

Comment: Yes, because it works for the other model. Also if I pass a hardcoded value of `1` it still won't work.

Comment: your code looks a little strange. Why do you have the same ID for 2 models? both your main model and the Video model have the same ID?

Comment: there are probably related but the same ID? you sure about that?

Comment: I am asking because your code looks ok, there is probably some very small that you are overlooking, not a coding issue I assume.

Comment: Please show any error that you get by opening `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: I am not getting any error, if anything `$vid` is just null because it can't find anything. @MihaiP. The ID is the foreign key for the video. The integrity of the database is correct too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are saying "The ID is the foreign key for the video. The integrity of the database is correct too."
but $vid is taken using the primary key

```
$vid = Video::model()->findByPk($id);
```

So you should probably have

```
$vid = Video::model()->findAll("FK_XXXX=:id", array(':id'=>$id));
```

Comment: What would the `FK_XXX` be? ForeignKey_TableName?

Comment: just the name of the field that makes the relation between Video and your model.

Comment: Also are you sure you have only 1 video per original model? why can't you have more?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need make this:
`$vid = Video::model()->findByPk($id);`

The actionUpdate load the data for update, the parameter $id seek the record to update

Answer (score -1):

you need comment this:

```
$model=$this->loadModel($id);
```

and try it.